# Android Studio Test fails junit.framework.AssertionFailedError

Tags: android, testing, gradle

i use the latest android studio version. I want to use its testing possibilities.
When I test my library project I get an error. 
This is where the error happens:

```
startActivity (intent, null, null);
```

The created intent before is already null. Delete the test manifest file doesn't change anything. I guess the manifest is not recognized.
Lint also marks this line red in the manifest (and everything I enter there):
    android:targetPackage="common.project"

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
at android.test.ActivityUnitTestCase.startActivity(ActivityUnitTestCase.java:147)
at common.project.test.MainActivityTest.setUp(MainActivityTest.java:27)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
```

my project structure looks like this
project

```
  \-library project
    \-src
      \-AndroidManifest.xml
      \-androidTest
        \-java
          \-common.project.test
            \-MainActivityTest.java
```

This is a library project. I want to set up testing now.
This is MainActivityTest.java

```
public class MainActivityTest extends android.test.ActivityUnitTestCase<MainActivity> {
    private MainActivity mActivity;
    private MenuItem forwardButton;

    public MainActivityTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(),
                MainActivity.class);
        startActivity (intent, null, null);
        mActivity = getActivity();
```

The Test Manifest looks this way:

```
    <application>
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />

    </application>

    <instrumentation
        android:targetPackage="common.project"
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" />

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `ActivityUnitTestCase.startActivity(Intent, Bundle, Object)` explicitly says:

**Do not call from your setUp() method. You must call this method from each of your test methods.**

Reference: [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityUnitTestCase.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent,%20android.os.Bundle,%20java.lang.Object%29)